# Does Python support embedding relative-path content?

Tags: python, embedded-resource

Rust supports `let some_text = include_str!("./data.txt");` and `let some_ba = include_bytes!("./data.bin");`, that is, embed (relative-path) content without using runtime instructions (nor filesystem nor HTTP). Does Python have the equivalent to include plain text or octet stream?

Comment: Yes. `with open("filename.txt", "r") as f: content = f.read()`.

Comment: Everything in python is effectively a runtime insturction since it is interpreted. You could write some preprocessing tool to parse a python project and insert the desired content for you, but there is nothing built-in for this

Comment: @MattDMo This seems to be instruction based: [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: @joshmeranda I was thinking on using the Python's built-in parser, but I hoped there was a built-in expression for that.

Comment: "Built-in parser" for what?  I thought your Rust examples don't parse anything, just replace literals with file/stream content.

Comment: Whatever you do you'll have to do it before you run the code. You could utilize the existing python interpreter library to do that but that is probably overkill in most cases. Either way, you'll need to work with more than just the parser to get things working as you expect them to

Comment: @KlasŠ. I meant using the parser for detecting certain expressions and interpreting them as file-embed expressions. But as joshmeranda said, that would be much work I guess.